# WebSphere and Unit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, websphere

Colleague,

Could you give couple of advises regarding Unit Test of EJB module in WebSphere environment. I try to searc in google and found

- arquillian(http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/). I found source of old version of container adapter for WAS on maven repository. To my regret this version can be built. Ready to use jar was not found in central repository.
- OpenEJB(http://openejb.apache.org/comparison.html ). As I understand coorecly this container work on local machine of developer. I will have a lot of problems with Mocked objects that shall be created on my local machine

Are there another tools or libraries for run unit test on remote environment?

Thank you in advance
Alexander

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Have you tried writing your unit tests in plain JUnit? If not, why not; if yes, what didn't work?

Comment: I would like to execute my test in application container because of this is native environment for application. Executing unit test locally is not good, application need to obtain resources from container, some of them are injected by application container.

Comment: What version of WebSphere are you trying to test your EJBs against?

Comment: @Alexander Are you sure you understand what unit testing is?